# Can i carry two iphone 6s from hongkong to india?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, cellphones

I m planning to buy 2 iphones 6s in hongkong, one for me and one for my girl friend , but I m not sure If I  will have any problem bringing the iPhone 6s even before it launches in india.

Comment: Why shouldn't they accept it? Just keep the receipts with you and pay customs.